# Installing ez library on R

Tags: r

I am new to R and feeling a bit confused. I am getting this error message

```
library(ez)
```

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>    versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>     namespace ‘reshape2’ 1.4.1 is already
>    loaded, but >= 1.4.2 is required Error: package or namespace load
>   failed for ‘ez’

I have already checked the version that I have and it says 1.4.2. What should I do?
Thank you SO much

Comment: Did you type `packageVersion("reshape2")` to check your package version ? With output `‘1.4.2’` ?

Comment: Yes..That is the answer that I got! 1.4.2

Comment: Re-install **ez** then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe ‘reshape2’ 1.4.1 is still loaded..try the following

```
remove.packages("reshape2")
remove.packages("ez")
install.packages("ez")
```

Should work afterwards.

If not then try this afterwards

```
detach("package:reshape2", unload=TRUE)
```

And additionally restart the R session.

Comment: Happy that I could help you :) Seems you are new to stackoverflow: There is a green checkmark to the left of every answer. By pressing this checkmark you can signal other users that an answer solved your problem. Which makes it easier for them.